# All possible combinations of indices in an array, as in nested multiple loops

Tags: combinations, julia

There is an array `[1, 2, ..., m]`, and there is an integer `n`.

If `m=2` and `n=3`, I want to obtain

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
```

It's like I do

```
for i=1:m
  for j=1:m
    for k=1:m
      \\ get [i, j, k]
    end
  end
end
```

But, both `m` and `n` are variables. How can I do this? I'm using Julia, but any general advice would be fine.

Comment: I think you could use either `Iterators` or `Cartesian`; does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950331/how-to-make-arbitrary-level-of-nested-for-loop) help?

Comment: @DSM Thanks. It was exactly what I was looking for. So, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you mean by "I want to obtain" and `\\ get [i, j, k]`, but you may find this useful/interesting.

```
julia> using Iterators

julia> collect(product(repeated(1:2,3)...))
8-element Array{(Int32,Int32,Int32),1}:
 (1,1,1)
 (2,1,1)
 (1,2,1)
 (2,2,1)
 (1,1,2)
 (2,1,2)
 (1,2,2)
 (2,2,2)

julia> A=reshape(1:8,(2,2,2))
2x2x2 Array{Int32,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3
 2  4

[:, :, 2] =
 5  7
 6  8

julia> for i in product(repeated(1:2,3)...)
         @show A[i...]
       end
A[i...] => 1
A[i...] => 2
A[i...] => 3
A[i...] => 4
A[i...] => 5
A[i...] => 6
A[i...] => 7
A[i...] => 8

julia> cartesianmap((k...)->println(A[k...]^2+1),tuple(repeated(2,3)...))
2
5
10
17
26
37
50
65
```

or even without the `Iterators` package ...

```
julia> cartesianmap((k...)->println(A[k...]),tuple(repmat([2],3)...))
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted your first example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Julia specific but what I do generally in such a case is (pseudo code):

```
array = [1, 1, 1, .., 1] # ones n times
while True
  # increased last element by one
  array(end) += 1
  # looking at overflows from end to beginning
  for i = n:-1:2
    if array(i) > m
      array(i) = 1
      array(i-1) += 1
    end
  end
  # if overflow in the first entry, stop
  if array(1) > m
    break
  end
  # do something with array, it contains the indices now
  ..
end
```